# VBA to return nth row number from a filtered table in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone please help me with finding the absolute row number of nth element after filter is applied in an excel table.

For example, I have filter on and have a visible range of data element. Now 20th (nth) row in this filtered range could be 60th row (absolute sense) when no filters are on. Is there a way to find the absolute row number using VBA?

Comment: Not sure why this question is being marked as off-topic. The question is very specific. And the problem is too simple, I would say, to necessitate the inclusion of code examples. As a matter of fact, any additional detail would likely have made his needs harder to distinguish. I think he did exactly what a newcomer should. +1 to you crazyfrog

Comment: Yeah this site can be super "over the top". Too bad, because truly, this question deserves a functionalized answer, not a "sub" and I created one which takes the desired visible row as an argument and returns absolute, but I can't share. Who benifits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest method is special cells. See below:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim Report As Worksheet

Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet ' Store the current worksheet in a variable (always a good idea)
Dim visRng As Range ' Creating a range variable to store our table, excluding any rows that are filtered out.
Set visRng = Report.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' Select only rows within the used range that are visible.

Dim r As Range 
For Each r In visRng.Rows ' Loop through each row in our visible range ...
    MsgBox (r.Row) ' ... and retrieve the "absolute" row number.
Next

End Sub
```

---

### EDIT

Tom claims this method will not work, but I'm pretty sure it does what you ask. Example:

Here is my original test table--unfiltered so you can see what we're doing.
[image: Unfiltered]

And then we filter a couple values somewhere in the middle of the table...

[image: Filtered]

Now when we run the script I posted above, our message box will show the "absolute" row number for each unfiltered row. Results are 1,3,4,5, and 7.

Answer (score 0):

As a function I suggest

```
Function RowNum(Target As Range) As Long
    RowNum = Target.Row
End Function
```

use by entering in a cell `=RowNum(E9)`. If you want the line relative to the table start and your table starts in -say- row 21, just subtract this from the result (you can use the same function to find the row of table start or course) ... e.g. `=rownum(A2)-rownum($A$1)` ... mind the absolute notation of table header!

If you don't like this as a function, you could use the SelectionChange event to display the row number of the selected cell in the message line (optionally depending on a "debug flag" somewhere in your sheet).

Tne non-VBA approach would be to use the CELL formula ... e.g. `=CELL("row",A1)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply MikeD, but I'm not looking to apply this on a specific cell. I want absolute row number (without filters on) of 20th visible row (after filter has been applied) in my table.

Comment: that is what it does ... go to the filtered table, advance to the 20th row and enter that function somewhere, pointing to any cell within that row .... you could of course look to the far left and read out the row number from Excel ... or I can elaborate more on how you can make this visible on the **status line**

Answer (score -1):

The answer brought up by @Lopsided wont work, if there are other hidden cells after the nth entry. They would then be added to the absolute position.

This'll work, you have to change n by yourself in the script. Changing that shouldn't be to hard. If you have any questions regarding that, feel free to ask. (;

```
Sub absoluteRowID()

Dim RowCount, hiddenRows As Integer

'relative position n
n = 5
i = 0

Do While i < n

i = i + 1
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden Then
'if there is a hidden row, position is incremented
n = n + 1
End If
'if there is no hidden row, nothing happens

Loop

MsgBox (i)



End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I tested my script with filtered rows in the middle of a large table. I'll post some screen shots to prove it does work as the OP requested.

Comment: Hey @Lopsided, sorry didn't want to offend you. Maybe I got your code wrong, but it seemd to me, that it counted _all_ invisible rows in the whole table. Would you be so kind to put some comments in your code? That would be very helpful. (:

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone ..... I used a combination of Lopsided and Tim's solution and it solved my problem. Really appreciated your help guys!!!!

Comment: Flagging the answers would be nice. <: