# How to skip to nth element of for next loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to return the nth visible element of a filtered table in Excel. [Current methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855848/vba-to-return-nth-row-number-from-a-filtered-table-in-excel) tell me to use the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` method, then loop through the elements whilst counting them with a `For Each... Next` loop.

This seems sub-optimal; I don't want to know about the first 19 ranges, only the 20th. Is there any way to skip straight to the 20th element of a loop?

Or maybe loop through the `.Areas` and count *their* sizes; meaning you only need to step into the `Area` which contains the nth element, then sub-loop within *that* area to locate the element precisely. Would this be faster?

Of course, if you can think of a better way to get the nth element of a filtered table, that'd be good too!

My code to get the table range is:

```
Dim inptTbl As Range
Set inptTbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("compiled").ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns("Company").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Then to loop through, well I haven't written that yet, but I guess:

```
i=0
Dim r As Range
For Each r in inptTbl
    i=i+1
    If i = 20 Then Exit For
Next r
Debug.Print r.Address
```

Looping through areas as described:

```
Set inptTbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("compiled").ListObjects("Table2")
Set test = inptTbl.ListColumns("Company").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

runningTot = 0
arIndex = 1
Do Until test.Areas(arIndex).Cells.Count + runningTot > 20
    runningTot = runningTot + test.Areas(arIndex).Cells.Count
    arIndex = arIndex + 1
Loop
i = 0
Dim r As Range
For Each r In test.Areas(arIndex)
    If i = 20 - runningTot Then Exit For
    i = i + 1
Next r
Debug.Print r.Address
```

Comment: From the moment you have a multi-area range, I think you will need to iterate on the areas, or on the visible cells one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Final Update**

As you mentioned you are looking for the most efficient way to go, I'd loop through the *areas* rather than individual cells.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim a As Range, rng As Range
    Dim n As Long, total As Long, adj As Long

    n = 20
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each a In rng.Areas
        adj = n - total
        total = total + a.Cells.Count
        If total >= n Then
            Debug.Print a.Cells(adj, 1).Address
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next a
End Sub
```

---

**Update #2**

In the interest of keeping this answer relatively clean, I deleted my previous efforts.

Finally, and still using `xlCellTypeVisible`, this should work in *any* case. It adjusts the size of your range until there are 20 visible cells and then returns the last cell in that range.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Dim n As Long

    n = 20 'update for your required value of n

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'relevant sheet name
        Set r = .Range("A1") 'where to start?
        Set rng = r.Resize(n, 1)
    End With

    While rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count < n
        Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    Wend

    Debug.Print rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1, r.Column).Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Ummm Yes? That was what I tried first, but bizarrely it included hidden cells despite `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` as a condition, resulting in `$A$20` being returned - regardless of filtering on `A1:A100`

Comment: If Some rows before the 20th row are hidden, that will still return A20. I tried `?Range("A1:A10, A30:A40").Cells(20, 1).address`, it returned `$A$20`.

Comment: Yeah, I've been testing this and get the same result. Except when you hide the first *n* cells (e.g. A1:A5) you would get $A$25. This must be something to do with Areas? I'll update my answer once I've found a better solution

Comment: Yes I suppose so. `.Cells` always indexes from the topleft cell in a split range, it doesn't check further.

Comment: I updated for another method - what do you think? This time I've tested it ;)

Comment: Your updated answer might nwork if the filtered rows (i.e. hidden) were contiguous but what if rows(2:4, 6:9, 12:17, 21:23, 27:30) were hidden?

Comment: Ah. Good spot.. back to the drawing board!

Comment: I gave in to looping in the end. But at least it's working! @Greedo

Comment: So the question is, I suppose, what is preferable; resizing and counting the size of the range 20 times or incrementing an integer by stepping through the range with a `For...Each` 20 times?

Comment: Or rather, re-counting/sizing more than 20 times, depending on how many  rows are filtered out

Comment: Given you could have a large number of hidden rows, I'd loop through the Areas, like you were suggesting. I've added a similar (but quicker) solution to yours using `Areas` @Greedo

Comment: Or just `a(adj).Address` Yep, that'll do it!

Comment: @Greedo, agreed that works, but greater minds than mine have had discussions on here about using the default method like that and it's generally discouraged. I think there are a few cases where you could run into some trouble

Answer (score 2):

A filtered range could have many discontiguous Areas (see [Get Excel filter results into VBA array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35885547/get-excel-filter-results-into-vba-array/35886134#35886134)). If you are looping through the visible cells, then use areas but if yu want to jump to the 20th visible elemen t, just run through a For Next loop until you meet the extent you want to retrieve.

```
Dim r As Long, v As Long

v = 20

With Selection
    For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
        v = v + (Not .Cells(r).EntireRow.Hidden)
        If v = 0 Then Exit For
    Next r

    Debug.Print .Cells(r).Value
End With
```

I've used `Selection` here for expediency; you can retrieve the actual cell range from your table.

Answer (score 1):

Would need to see your full code ideally, but instead of using `For Each....Next`, you could count the visible cells and do something like

```
Sub test()
Dim vcells as Long

vcells = Activesheet.Usedrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count

For i = 20 to vcells
    `your code here
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I've added the code. I'm not quite sure what your code does though: you count the visible rows in the filter range to get an upper limit for your loop, I see that, but what is the significance of starting from `i = 20`?

Comment: @Greedo because you wanted to start from the 20th iteration, I understood from your question once you have the filtered range, you want to ignore the first 19 ranges.

Comment: Ahh, I see, I think you misunderstood my meaning there. What I meant was that I don't care about the *properties* of the first 19 *visible* cells, I only care about the properties (specifically the address) of the 20th (or nth) visible cell.