# How to find the number of rows in a range after filtering

Tags: excel, vba, filter

The code gives me: Application defined or object defined error.

```
Sub test()

Dim rCell As Range
    Set rCell = Rows(1, 0).Offset(2, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1)
    If rCell <> "" Then
        MsgBox rCell.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to know whether there is a value in the cell on the second row (since the first row is the header) that is visible after I have filtered some data.

I'm filtering a database and most of the time after one filter it will have the data required but sometimes it still needs additional filtering.

Another way to look at my problem is: If there are more than two visible rows, continue with the filtering program, else continue macro.

Comment: Apologies for my old answer, I misread the question. Take a look at this answer, I think it's what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/28856922/2727437

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this gives me the information of the row. But what I trying to do is to know if there are more then one line visible. If so continue filtering if not end if. That is why I was looking at the third row of the visible cells and verify if it was empty. Your code give me the fact that there are more then one row, and loops through them where as I only want to know if there are more than one to continue filtering or not. Does it make sense?

Comment: What is the range of the cells before they are filtered? You might be able to just say `If Range(<unfiltered range>).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.count > 1 Then` if that's all you want to know

Comment: Well, I'm filtering a database. Most of the time after one filter it will have the data required. However sometimes it needs more types of filter. So maybe another way to look at it is:if there are more than two visible row,

Comment: sorry I hit enter on my previous comment before I was done. So maybe another way to look at it is: if there are more than two visible row continue with the filtering program else got to Continue macro. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so here's how you could get a count of the visible rows in a range or on the worksheet:

```
Function VisibleRowcount() As Long

    Dim count As Long

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        For i = 1 To .Areas.count
            For j = 1 To .Areas(i).Rows.count
                count = count + 1
            Next j
        Next i
    End With

    VisibleRowcount = count

End Function
```

Since what you really want is to do more operations if x amount of rows are still visible after filtering, here's how you would use this function to solve your problem:

```
Sub main()

    If VisibleRowcount > 2 Then
        'your code here
    End If

End Sub
```

Note that my function does not like you if there are no visible cells after a filter. Sometimes it likes to return 1, sometimes 0 - but my testing has so far been correct on cases where at least one cell still is showing.

---

If you're reading this in the future and you would like for it to handle cases with no visible cells, let me know via comments and i'll revisit this :)

Comment: Awesome!! this works perfectly. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: @ValS Glad it helped! Please consider clicking the checkbox to accept it as the best answer :)